# ERROR Error: A drawer was already declared for 'position="start"'

Tags: mat-sidenav

Mat-drawer-container
I'm Using 2 drawers respectively position start and position end
but still I'm getting above mention error

I am using angular 15. and material V.15

```
<mat-drawer-container>
  <mat-drawer position="start"></mat-drawer>
  <mat-drawer position="end"></mat-drawer>
  <mat-drawer-content></mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

I also tried align attribute on mat-drawer but its not working.

Comment: Could it be that you don't have </mat-drawer-container> tag to close the container?